# uigrid custom filter rows are note getting unselected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have custom filters implemented in ui grid for multiple columns and this filtering works very fine.

Now when i do the Reset All Filter, it works functionally however rows which are selected for Filters remains selected. This is really disturbing. I want to deselect all rows in the filters as soon I click Reset All Filter but this is now happening.

Did anyone faced this problem??

Individually clearing selected rows for a single filter
...
$scope.gridPopupApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
...

UI Grid filter example
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20306%20Custom%20Filters

Comment: sorry as i dont have code to show in plunkr. But I want to get hold of gridAPI variable for all the filters in memory

Comment: here is a sample plunker implementation for this problem

https://plnkr.co/plunk/bZp3llQ6xL3s2aSW